# ROC multiclass with cut-off, sensitivity and specificity

Tags: r, proc, roc

I've been searching about multiclass ROC curves and despite founding a nice function multiclass.roc from pROC in R I still don't get what I need.

This function only provides the AUC from the summarized categories of my multiclass variable, I would like to have also the CUt-Off, Specificity and Sensitivity for this multiclass case.

My categorical variable is education level with 5 classes and I want to get the summarized ROC curve with its informations for this case.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps some sample data, perhaps with the use of `dput()`? Some code to show what you've gotten with `pROC`?

Comment: The mlr package provides functionality for creating ROC curves (see [the tutorial](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/roc_analysis/index.html)) and is also able to handle multi-class cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, here a sample of my data:

> dados[c(1:20),c(4,5)]
>      school.level camcog
>   1             3     78
>   2             3     91
>   3             2     63
>   4             3     72
>   5             1     40
>   6             3     38
>   7             3     51
>   8             1     32
>   9             3     41
>   10            1     60
>   11            3     77
>   12            4     64
>   13            3     64
>   14            3     47
>   15            3     87
>   16            2     90
>   17            5     69
>   18            1     37
>   19            3     89
>   20            4     75

library(pROC)

> multiclass.roc(escolaridade,camcog,plot=T, percent=TRUE)
>   Call:
>   multiclass.roc.default(response = school.level, predictor = camcog,     percent = TRUE, plot = T)

Data: camcog with 5 levels of school.level 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
Multi-class area under the curve: 75.95%

---

And with pROC there is no way of getting the cut-off, specificity and sensitivity